# MAC OS Sierra 10.12.6 - does not accept region preference changes

Tags: macos, terminal, command-line

For whatever reason, the region preference changed from Brazil to United States (Custom) and I cannot change it back to Brazil. The currency changed to USD and I can also not change it back to BR. The date format displayed is American, the change back to European style date is not accepted either. Any other preferences in Language & Region as well as Date & Time can be changed without any problems.

I tried to:

- Reset NVRAM
- Repair the disk with Disk Utility
- Booting into single-user mode and ran fsck -yf
- Clear caches with OnyX

all without success.

I can also not locate the .GlobalPreferences.plist in ~/Library/Preferences/

Creating a new user account for test purposes solved the problem and all changes in the preferences were accepted. So it seems to be somehow user account related. However, I would like to continue to use the old user account and to understand what caused this problem.

Did anyone experienced this problem before?

Is there a command line for doing these changes? (I have very basic experience with Terminal)

In which .plists are these preferences stored?

Can anybody help me?  Thank you very much in advance.

Joe